# Iterating through an array of objects using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the array of object below:

```
function person(first, last, RPI, o, t, u) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.RPI =  RPI;
    this.o = o;
    this.t = t;
    this.u = u;
}

var MD = new person('Mike', 'D', 1234, '', '', '');
var AY = new person('Adam', 'Y', 5678, '', '', '');
var AH = new person('Adam', 'H', 1212, '', '', '');

var personArray = new Array(MD, AY, AH);
```

How would I iterate the RPI value from each object into this formula?

```
function selector(x){
//do something with x.RPI
}
```

I've tried:

```
$.each(personArray , selector (personArray[person].RPI){
selector(x)
});
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong with my each statement?

Comment: `personArray = {MD, AY, AHR, DD};` is not an array. Typo?

Comment: Yes. Typo. :-). Still the problem persisted.

Comment: Your use of each is wrong. The function is being called not referenced in the second argument. You have this weird {} after it.... Look at the documentation on how to use it http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.each` callback needs to be a function
Do something like the following:

```
var personArray = new Array (MW, MT, DR)
$.each(personArray, function(index, person){
   console.log(person.RPI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your $.each to

```
$.each(personArray , selector);
```

and then

```
function selector(index, item){
    //do something with item.RPI
}
```